# IMG title edit using CSS but identifying by PHP call

Tags: php, css, image, title

I currently have an info image in a table.

When I hover over the icon it displays the artist description in the tool tip because i have it set up to do so.

```
<img src='images/info.png' width="20" height="20" title="<?php echo $artist['description']; ?>">
```

This is my CSS

```
            img[title="<?php echo $artist['description']; ?>"]{
        border-radius:50%;
        background-color: red;}
```

It doesnt work. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: It's the code you are sending to the browser doesn't behave the way you want. Show us that, not the PHP that generates it.

Comment: What are you expecting the CSS to do? Is the background image translucent? If not, how do you expect to see the background through it?